# Infragistics grid row selection of one page is mimicking to next pages

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, webdatagrid

I have an Infragistics grid where the first column is `Checkbox` column to select the row. Multiple row selection is enabled. Now, the issue is that, the checkbox checked state of one page is persisting to next pages too. For example, if I checked 3rd and 5th row of Grid in first page and navigating to next page, in this case, the previous clicked row position from first page is being mimicked and 3rd and 5th row of this page too is being selected without performing any selection activity on the checkbox.

Is there some property to disable this. What can be the possible reason and how to resolve it ?

Update

```
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="SampleGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
Width="99%" ItemCssClass="gridRow" EnableDataViewState="true"   CssClass="grid"
 DataKeyFields="EO" HeaderCaptionCssClass="gridHeader"   AltItemCssClass="gridRow" OnColumnSorted="SampleGrid_OnSorting" OnInitializeRow="SampleGrid_OnInitializeRow">
<Columns>
<ig:TemplateDataField Header-Text="" Width="4%" Key="ChkBox">
<ItemTemplate>
<als:CheckBox ID="chkPkgNo" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</ig:TemplateDataField>
```

Upadate 2

```
 if(DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0){
 GRID.ClearDataSource();
 GRID.DataSource = DataSet.Tables[0];
 GRID.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: it will most probably be some CSS classes they apply to style it as selected. You can manually remove those and apply to the first row, but if you ask on their forums i'm sure someone would have already gone through that and given a decent answer.

Comment: Do you need to use the EnableDataViewState=true?

Comment: @KonstantinDinev Yes, it is required, so that I can see the rows selected if I come back to previous pages of the grid

Answer (score 1):

You could disable persistence using this option: http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ui.iggridselection#options:persist

However, persistence shouldn't behave like this. Are you, by any chance, using dummy data that has repeating records and no PK defined? Since persistence is on by default and it relies on having unique identifiers for each row, Selection will try to create some if no PK is defined using the records' checksums. Repeating records will therefore result in repeating ids which may cause the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: We haven't used Ignite-UI in our project. What will be the solution in case of Infragistics grid ?

Comment: What product are you using, if not Ignite UI?

Comment: @KonstantinDinev I have updated my post with relevant client side code. `EnableDataViewState= True` is persisting the selection to next pages.

Comment: Oh, so that's WebDataGrid and not the jQuery grid. I will retag the question.

Comment: @KonstantinDinev Yes, Any idea what is being missed ?

Comment: What version of the product are you using?

Comment: @KonstantinDinev I am using `Version=13.2`

Comment: To be honest, this is probably a bug in that version. The version is old and unsupported, so can you try a newer version (16.2 for example) and see if you still have the same problem?

Comment: @KonstantinDinev Thanks. I have updated my post with my Server side code. Please have a look and advice, if there is any way we can resolve the issue in the current version. Its not possible for me to update from 13.2 as my entire application is designed on the same. Thanks

Comment: @KonstantinDinev I googled and got if we reinitiaze the grid in `protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)` it will sort the issue. Could you please guide me in the exact line of code that needs to be written to reinitiate the grid

Comment: @user1197114 I think what you need is to clear the data source and rebind on prerender (the code that you already have in your example).